# Excel, Changing Values based on Duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

I have 3 columns on excel filled with previous data.

Column A is the name of employees [Jordan Smith]

Column B is the name of employees that clocked in on a certain day,this won't be added to the final spreadsheet. It's just to change the date in column C. (this changes everyday)[Jordan Smith]

Column C is the date that the employee LAST clocked in (could be yesterday, 2 days ago, etc) [12/01/21]

I'm trying to change the value in **column C** based on the employees that logged in on a certain day Column B.

If there's a name on Column B that is identical to the name in Column A, then Column C will need to be changed.

I know there's a conditional format to highlight duplicate values, (Column B and Column A), but I need to change the value in Column C based on the duplicate values. There's probably a really easy IF Function for this but I haven't been successful.

[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UDcQ.png) tldr: change column C if column B value = column a

Comment: This will probably be a lot easier to understand if you actually produce an example of what you have got (in terms of your 3 columns) and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DMM does my edit help or should I add an image?

Comment: Do you think it's ok if add a helper column in column D to help you changde the date?

Comment: @Lee yes that would be okay! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, just to rephrase. You have in A say

```
John
James
Joe
```

Then in C

```
12/01/22
13/02/22
05/02/22
```

Meaning i.e. James last clocked in on 13/02/2022.

Now in B, you have (for today)

```
James 
Joe
```

Which means C must update to

```
12/01/22
02/03/22
02/03/22
```

Tomorrow, you will edit column B and C must be updated again.

You would need to create a new column in D with the formula

```
 =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,B2:B100,0)),C2,$F$2)
```

Where F2 contains the date of the last column B update. Now, everyday before logging the new data in B or changing F2, copy and paste **as values** all the dates in D over to C. Now update B and F2.

As an alternative you can venture into the world of VBA macros and program an "update last clock-in dates" button. The macro would then do the formula part (no column D required) and update the static "value only" dates in column C all in one click.

Comment: Hey Mobus,

I'm getting an error when I try that formula (You've entered too many arguments for this function)

Thank you so much for helping me with this.

Comment: Updated! Kindly remember to checkmark the solution if it worked for you.

Comment: @Mobus  ,, please add some sample data along with the formula has been used as posted by #Lee above,,, help all to understand that how it's working !!

Answer (score 1):

Add the helper column and enther the formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10,A2)=1,DATE(2002,2,2),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Good one @Lee  +10 ☺